# Oracle Application, button to copy data to other table

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

In my oracle apex application there are two tables e.g. tbl1 & tbl2. I have a report and form on tbl1. In that form I want a button that will copy a specified row to tbl2.
Any ideas, I'm pretty new to oracle applications.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new button (which will fire action to copy)
2. Create new process on the same page, type - `PL/SQL`
3. In process properties: `Process point` - `After submit`, `Conditions` - choose your button
4. In process source:

   `begin`
     `insert into tbl2`
     `select * from tbl1`
     `where <your conditions>;`
   `end;`